# OpenISO8583.Net BCD Formatted Track 2

Tags: iso8583, openiso8583.net

Here is another question.

My requirement for Track 2 (bit 35) is:

> Z (Numeric + X 'D' (BCD, ½ byte representation of D [1101] as a field separator between Primary Account Number and Expiration Date), BCD — When an odd number of digits, pack right-most half byte to '0'. Size: Variable to 37, preceded by a one-byte, BCD length indicator

The default template definition has bit 35 as a 2 byte length Ascii field so I am sure that is not it. I changed it to BcdVar(1, 37, Formatters.Bcd).

Taking a dummy track2 example of:

12345678901234567=9999999999999999999

I replace the '=' separator with the 0x0D integer value which translates to "13" (1101). We now have:

12345678901234567139999999999999999999

Does this make sense? I don't think this is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: I have also realized that the conversion to BCD needs to left justified. That is padded on the right side if needed, not on the left like a normal number. This applies to bit 2 (PAN) as well. It seems I am going to have a created a new BCD formatter class to support this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've run into a "feature" of OpenIso8583.Net.  When you work with the field values using `msg[3] = "123456"`, you must always work with the unpacked values.

For this track2 data, you need to build up the track 2 as `12345678901234567D9999999999999999999`.  Note the 'D' in the middle of the data as a separator.

Now in your `Template` set field 35 to have a BCD formatter, essentially.

```
template[Bit._035_TRACK_2_DATA] = FieldDescriptor.BcdVar(2, 37, FieldValidators.Track2)
```

Comment: On the source code I have that definition is invalid. FieldDescriptor.BcdVar doesn't take a FieldValidators parameter only a length formatter. If I defined it with the Formatters.Bcd it throws an exception when trying to convert the 'D' value. Also the padding have to be on the right side and BCD puts it in the left.

Comment: I am not sure if I am doing the correct thing but I think these fields should be treated as the equivalent of binary (hex values) with the extra padding since the field size is variable. At some point I realized that the resulting BCD value was exactly the same as the one from a hex to byte array conversion. I am creating a new formatter class to support this. My initial tests seems to be working as expected.

Comment: I marked this as answered. I guess its just a matter of learning the code and customize whatever functionality is not there. Thanks for creating this library.

Comment: Hi El, could you please share your new formatter code? I see I'm moving the same way. TIA

Answer (score 0):

I sort of duplicated the question ([Track2 in BCD - 'D' character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168207/track2-in-bcd-d-character)).

Treating the field as Binary (**with a BCD-Length-Indicator!!!**) is a cute trick, which might do the trick. But, still - there is no method:

```
  public static FieldDescriptor.BinaryVar(..., ILengthFormatter lengthFormatter)
```

so instead of adding it (which should be done anyway, for cases of BinaryVar fields), one can add a:

```
  public static FieldDescriptor.BcdVar(..., IFieldValidator validator)
```

and call:

```
  msg[Bit._035_TRACK_2_DATA] = FieldDescriptor.BcdVar(2, 37, FieldValidators.Track2);
```

the 'D' will be treated as BCD - what do banks know...

---

Regarding the **right-padding** - I guess that's where the **Adjuster** comes handy. Again, we need to add a static method with an *Adjuster* parameter like this:

```
  var setAdjuster = new LambdaAdjuster(setLambda: value => value.PadRight(value.length + 1, '0'));
```

It's true - you can pad the value prior to setting the field, but that's not fun (we're geeks, aren't we?).

---

Regarding **adding static methods to FieldDescriptor** - I guess it's possible to use the generic

```
  public static IFieldDescriptor Create(ILengthFormatter lengthFormatter, IFieldValidator fieldValidator, IFormatter formatter, Adjuster adjuster)
```

but I'm new to C# and would be glad to get confirmation regarding my theories.

Thanks.